# Avoid overlap between touch and click android in OnTouch(), in IOnTouchListener?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

[image: Image of my App]

I am creating this app.

> code of my onsingletapup.cs file

```
class SingleTapUp : Android.Views.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener 
    {

        public override bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
           // Toast.MakeText(this,, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

> here is my mainactivity.cs

```
    public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity, View.IOnTouchListener 
    {

         GestureDetector gestureDetector;
     float _viewX;
         float _viewY;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            PopulateListView(someList,anynumbertoshow)

        }
 private void QueueListView(Queue<FeedItem> feedItemsList, int count)
        {

            RelativeLayout rl = this.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.newsContainer);
            if(rl.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
            {
                this.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.newsList).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

                rl.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
            Paint layerPaint = new Paint();
            layerPaint.AntiAlias = true;
            layerPaint.FilterBitmap = true;
            layerPaint.Dither = true;
            // RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null);
            rl.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, layerPaint);

            rl.SetClipChildren(false);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            //this.progressDialog.Dismiss();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                FeedItem rss = theNewsQueue.Dequeue();
                var viewObj = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewTile, rl, false);
                TextView tv = viewObj.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
                TextView link = viewObj.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.link);
                link.Text = rss.Link;
                tv.Text = rss.Title;
                viewObj.Rotation = angle;
                angle = rnd.Next(-3, 3);
                viewObj.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, layerPaint);
                rl.AddView(viewObj);
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapUp());
                viewObj.SetOnTouchListener(this); //Here I am adding my listener to all my control
                rl.SetLayerType(LayerType.Hardware, layerPaint);

                theNewsQueue.Enqueue(rss);
                rss = null;

            }


        }
        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {

            if (gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e))
           {
               //will detect a click and open in browser
               return true;
            }
            else
            {
                int initialTouchX = 0, initialTouchY = 0;
                int newx = 0;
                var x = v.Left;
                switch (e.Action)
                {

                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                        {
                            _viewX = e.GetX();
                            _viewY = e.GetY();
                            initialTouchX = (int)e.RawX;
                            initialTouchY = (int)e.RawY;
                            break;
                        }
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        {
                            int lastX = (int)e.GetX();
                            int lastY = (int)e.GetY();

                            if ((x - newx) > 40)
                            {
                             //right Swipe
                                sendViewToBack(v);




                            }
                            else if ((newx - x > 40))
                            {
                                //left Swipe
                                sendViewToBack(v);

                            }


                            break;
                        }

                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                        {
                          //  click = false;
                            var left = (int)(e.RawX - _viewX);
                            newx = left;
                            var right = (int)(left + v.Width);

                            var top = (int)(e.RawY - _viewY);
                            var bottom = (int)(top + v.Height);

                            v.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);

                            break;
                        }

                }
            }
            // _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
            return true;
        }
        public void sendViewToBack(View child)
        {
            var parent = (ViewGroup)child.Parent;
            if (null != parent)
            {
                parent.RemoveView(child);
                if(viewType==0)
                parent.AddView(QueueListView (theNewsQueue), 0);
                else
                    parent.AddView(QueueListView (theNewsQueue), parent.ChildCount-1);
            }
        }

}
```

Now my question is on some devices my current code is giving some abnormal behavior. Like even if I perform **OnSingleTapUp()** which is supposed to perform click operation but it is performing a move operation. My question is what is wrong with my code so that it is not working correctly. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The onTouch and onClick doesn't work together. In all the cases the onTouch is going to get the priority, in fact onClick in also sort of fine implementation of onTouch. If you want to have onClick sort of functionality, let go the original onClick and try to handle that in onTouch. You can take help of the GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener in Xamarin. For an example to override the double tap you can do it like this

```
class MyDoubleTapListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {           

        public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
        {
            //Your code here

            return false;
        }
    }
```

and then in your activity

```
public class Test : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
        private GestureDetector _gestureDetector = null;


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {

            _gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyDoubleTapListener (this));


        _editText.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }


        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {    
            return _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }


}
```

GestureDetector also provides you other methods that you can overide to suit your need. Follow this, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.GestureDetector/

Comment: I want to move the control with the ontouch event

Comment: I am using the code which you have posted working fine but as I have asked sometimes there is a overlap between touch and click so click is not being triggered

Comment: The only thing I am doing is singletapup

Comment: See, the onClick and onTouch wont work together but you can replicate the behaviour of onClick. The onClick is fired by system, when you take of your finger of the view after a set time. I think this time is 500ms. So now in onTouch when down event is fired start a timer and check this timer for 500ms in up event. If time matches then consider that as click. For more touch events you need to explore the api document, link is provided in the answer already

Comment: is it the only way possible to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: yes, because you just cannot combine the onClick or onTouch. You have to go through onTouch Api doc to have better understanding on how to do it.

Comment: yes because the return value of onClick and onTouch are different. The code I have written is working fine but in some device (like samsung galaxy j1) it is not working.or can you suggest any other way to achieve my requirement. I have relativelayout one over other I want to swipe between the layouts and click on it to open.

Comment: I have added the image of my app in the 1st link I have provided :)

Comment: ok, i saw you image and understood your purpose. You can implement the flings event in onTouch. See saying it again, it wont be simple to do but you have to implement your interaction login in onTouch, onClick is not going to work that way.

Comment: thanks for your response but I just want to ask why my OnTouch(View v,MotionEvent e) on some device triggars only touch not singletapup. I have nowhere implemented OnClick so it should be out of dissusion I am updating my question so that you can get a better view what I need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get exactly what your are trying to do inside onTouch interface. Anyway there's some points you must know:

1) When you handle a touch event, onTouch method returns a boolean that indicates if event was consumed (true) or not (false). If you consume touch event related to click, click listener won't be triggered. So, make sure you are only consuming what is desired.

2) When you set listeners as onClick or onTouch to some view, it becomes clickable and touchable, respectively, if it wasn't. If you are setting this attributes to false in some part of your code make sure it's enabled again when you want to handle such events.

Comment: I want to move the control with the ontouch event

Comment: I can see two options for you, and I'm not sure if both works, i'ts just my guess. Dealing with returned boolean flags by onTouch could make onTouch and onClick work together. Another way is to use method performClick() programmatically to call onClick method of the view whenever you want. Of course, it would be a little painful if you have to implement more complex events as LongClick based on Action Events as Up and Down.